# Conflict between encoding charsets when generating irc stats from ZNC logs with PISG

Tags: linux, character-encoding, irc-bouncer

I'm using [PISG](http://pisg.sourceforge.net/) to generate stats for an IRC channel.
Log files are from [ZNC log module](http://wiki.znc.in/Log).
Logs are in this folder: `~/.znc/moddata/log/`
The problem is that when i'm generating stats with PISG, my stats.html
shows some stranges characters (�) in place of letters with accents (éèàç,..)

Additionnals infos :

- I use **ZNC 1.4** and I cant update
- ZNC is using UTF-8 internaly
- I use PISG v0.73 which is the latest version
- Generated statistics are in french ( I need support of 'éèçàù' etc. )

PISG **do have** an option to specify LogCharset and Charset (Charset is used for generated page), but I'm unable to have it to display those letters in a correct way. I'm not sure about which charset to specify there.

Also, [ZNC supports characters encoding](http://wiki.znc.in/Charset) in core since **1.6**
but as i'm using **1.4** I need to use [ZNC Charset/old module](http://wiki.znc.in/Charset/old) it is unclear to me of which charset i need to set-up.

If I do `file -bi` on any of my logfiles, it returns "application/stream   charset:binary".

Here's a short version of my PISG config file:

```
<channel="#chanel">
    LogDir="/home/math/.znc/moddata/log"
    LogPrefix = "math_network_#chanel"
    Format = "energymech"
    Maintainer = "math"
    OutputFile = "/home/math/public_html/irc_stats/stats.html"
    Network = "Network"
    Lang = "FR"
</channel>

    <set channel="#chanel">
#   <set LogCharset="UTF-8">
#   <set Charset="UTF-8">
```

I'm about 90% certain that my problem could be solved with ZNC's charset/old module **only**.

Any idea would be welcome.